# curl with ntlm authentication works in command line but not inside php

Tags: php, curl, ntlm

I have to connect from a Centos Host to a IIS with curl.

Using **curl** with **--ntlm** option works fine on the command line, but non in php. Server is a Microsoft IIS and answers first with 401 Unauthorized, on second pass with 200 OK.

After investigating for several hours i did not find a working solution..

When i use curl on the command line (centos 6.4) to retrieve the content of a service:

```
curl -v http://example.com/do.asmx --ntlm -u DOMAIN\\username:password
```

the server answers successfully with this code:

```
* About to connect() to example.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying nn.nn.nn.nn... connected
* Connected to example.com (nn.nn.nn.nn) port 80 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* Server auth using NTLM with user 'DOMAIN\username'
> GET /do.asmx HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: NTLM xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (i386-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
< Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
< WWW-Authenticate: NTLM xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
< Date: Thu, 07 Jan 2016 19:28:04 GMT
< Content-Length: 341
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://example.com/do.asmx'
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host example.com
* Connected to example.com (nn.nn.nn.nn) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using NTLM with user 'DOMAIN\username'
> GET /do.asmx HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: NTLM xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (i386-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< Persistent-Auth: true
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE8
< Date: Thu, 07 Jan 2016 19:28:04 GMT
< Content-Length: 5340
< 


<html>
...
```

ok, so far, this works fine. now i tried to do the same in php :

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/do.asmx' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "DOMAIN\\username:password" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );


$output = curl_exec($ch);

print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($output);
```

but nothing happens. the results are

**print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)) :**

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://example.com/do.asmx
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0
    [namelookup_time] => 0.021611
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

**echo curl_error($ch) :**

```
connect() timed out!
```

**var_dump($output) :**

```
bool(false)
```

how could this problem be solved ? this goes beyond my knowledge ..

Comment: you sure it's curl? maybe your firewall isn't allowing the http process that php's running under to make outgoing connections. if it was permissions/authentication thing, you couldn't be getting "timed out", you'd be getting "access denied" or something.

Comment: Thanks, Marc, you're right. I worked on my development server with a VPN connection and after I put it on the migration server, it runs fine.

Comment: @JoachimRuisz how you configured you firewall? I'm under the same problem right now

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you remove the base64 strings from the http header `Authorization: NTLM TL...` since it is possible to decode it and read your domain and credentials exposing you to a huge security risk.

Remove those IP addresses as well unless they are internal only (even still, remove them anyways).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you to check your security policies. Your firewall can block some packages.